# VHDL: logical block 'dcm' with type 'DCM_BASE' could not be resolved

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx

I keep getting the following error when I go to implement my design in Xilinx ISE:

```
ERROR:NgdBuild:604 - logical block 'dcm' with type 'DCM_BASE' could not be
   resolved. A pin name misspelling can cause this, a missing edif or ngc file,
   case mismatch between the block name and the edif or ngc file name, or the
   misspelling of a type name. Symbol 'DCM_BASE' is not supported in target
   'spartan6'.
```

Here is the top.vhd file:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Company: 
-- Engineer: 
-- 
-- Create Date:    22:18:21 05/28/2011 
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    top - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity top is
   port (
        clk_in : in  STD_LOGIC;
        tx     : out STD_LOGIC;
        rx     : in  STD_LOGIC
    );
end top;

architecture Behavioral of top is

    COMPONENT miner
    generic ( DEPTH : integer );
    PORT(
        clk : IN std_logic;
        step : IN std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
        data : IN std_logic_vector(95 downto 0);
        state : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (255 downto 0);
        nonce : IN std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);          
        hit : OUT std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;

    COMPONENT uart
    PORT(
        clk : IN std_logic;
        rx : IN std_logic;
        txdata : IN std_logic_vector(48 downto 0);
        txwidth : IN std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
        txstrobe : IN std_logic;
        txbusy : OUT std_logic;          
        tx : OUT std_logic;
        rxdata : OUT std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        rxstrobe : OUT std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;

    constant DEPTH : integer := 6;

    signal clk : std_logic;
    signal clk_dcmin : std_logic;
    signal clk_dcmout : std_logic;
    signal data : std_logic_vector(95 downto 0);
    signal state : std_logic_vector(255 downto 0);
    signal nonce : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal currnonce : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal load : std_logic_vector(343 downto 0);
    signal loadctr : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    signal loading : std_logic := '0';
    signal hit : std_logic;
    signal txdata : std_logic_vector(48 downto 0);
    signal txwidth : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    signal txstrobe : std_logic;
    signal rxdata : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal rxstrobe : std_logic;
    signal step : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0) := "000000";

begin


    currnonce <= nonce - 2 * 2 ** DEPTH;

  clk_buf : BUFG
      port map (I=>clk_dcmout,
                O=>clk);

  clk_in_buf : IBUFG
      port map (I=>clk_in,
                O=>clk_dcmin);

    dcm : DCM_BASE
        generic map (
            CLKDV_DIVIDE => 2.0, -- Divide by: 1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5,4.0,4.5,5.0,5.5,6.0,6.5
            -- 7.0,7.5,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0,15.0 or 16.0
            CLKFX_DIVIDE => 10, -- Can be any interger from 1 to 32
            CLKFX_MULTIPLY => 12, -- Can be any integer from 2 to 32
            CLKIN_DIVIDE_BY_2 => FALSE, -- TRUE/FALSE to enable CLKIN divide by two feature
            CLKIN_PERIOD => 10.0, -- Specify period of input clock in ns from 1.25 to 1000.00
            CLKOUT_PHASE_SHIFT => "NONE", -- Specify phase shift mode of NONE or FIXED
            CLK_FEEDBACK => "NONE", -- Specify clock feedback of NONE or 1X
            DCM_AUTOCALIBRATION => TRUE,
            DCM_PERFORMANCE_MODE => "MAX_SPEED", -- Can be MAX_SPEED or MAX_RANGE
            DESKEW_ADJUST => "SYSTEM_SYNCHRONOUS", -- SOURCE_SYNCHRONOUS, SYSTEM_SYNCHRONOUS or
            -- an integer from 0 to 15
            DFS_FREQUENCY_MODE => "LOW", -- LOW or HIGH frequency mode for frequency synthesis
            DLL_FREQUENCY_MODE => "LOW", -- LOW, HIGH, or HIGH_SER frequency mode for DLL
            DUTY_CYCLE_CORRECTION => TRUE, -- Duty cycle correction, TRUE or FALSE
            FACTORY_JF => X"F0F0", -- FACTORY JF Values Suggested to be set to X"F0F0"
            PHASE_SHIFT => 0, -- Amount of fixed phase shift from -255 to 1023
            STARTUP_WAIT => TRUE
        ) -- Delay configuration DONE until DCM LOCK, TRUE/FALSE
        port map (
            CLK0 => open, -- 0 degree DCM CLK ouptput
            CLK180 => open, -- 180 degree DCM CLK output
            CLK270 => open, -- 270 degree DCM CLK output
            CLK2X => open, -- 2X DCM CLK output
            CLK2X180 => open, -- 2X, 180 degree DCM CLK out
            CLK90 => open, -- 90 degree DCM CLK output
            CLKDV => open, -- Divided DCM CLK out (CLKDV_DIVIDE)
            CLKFX => clk_dcmout, -- DCM CLK synthesis out (M/D)
            CLKFX180 => open, -- 180 degree CLK synthesis out
            LOCKED => open, -- DCM LOCK status output
            CLKFB => '0', -- DCM clock feedback
            CLKIN => clk_dcmin, -- Clock input (from IBUFG, BUFG or DCM)
            RST => '0' -- DCM asynchronous reset input
        );

    miner0: miner
       generic map ( DEPTH => DEPTH )
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            step => step,
            data => data,
            state => state,
            nonce => nonce,
            hit => hit
        );

    serial: uart
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            tx => tx,
            rx => rx,
            txdata => txdata,
            txwidth => txwidth,
            txstrobe => txstrobe,
            txbusy => open,
            rxdata => rxdata,
            rxstrobe => rxstrobe 
        );

    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            step <= step + 1;
            if conv_integer(step) = 2 ** (6 - DEPTH) - 1 then
                step <= "000000";
                nonce <= nonce + 1;
            end if;
            txdata <= "-------------------------------------------------";
            txwidth <= "------";
            txstrobe <= '0';
            if rxstrobe = '1' then
                if loading = '1' then
                    if loadctr = "101011" then
                        state <= load(343 downto 88);
                        data <= load(87 downto 0) & rxdata;
                        nonce <= x"00000000";
                        txdata <= "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000010";
                        txwidth <= "001010";
                        txstrobe <= '1';
                        loading <= '0';
                    else
                        load(343 downto 8) <= load(335 downto 0);
                        load(7 downto 0) <= rxdata;
                        loadctr <= loadctr + 1;
                    end if;
                else
                    if rxdata = "00000000" then
                        txdata <= "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000";
                        txwidth <= "001010";
                        txstrobe <= '1';
                    elsif rxdata = "00000001" then
                       loadctr <= "000000";
                        loading <= '1';
                    end if;
                end if;
            elsif hit = '1' then
                txdata <= currnonce(7 downto 0) & "01" & currnonce(15 downto 8) & "01" & currnonce(23 downto 16) & "01" & currnonce(31 downto 24) & "01000000100";
                txwidth <= "110010";
                txstrobe <= '1';
            elsif nonce = x"ffffffff" and step = "000000" then
                txdata <= "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000110";
                txwidth <= "110010";
                txstrobe <= '1';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;    


end Behavioral;
```

Other info:

- Device is Xilinx xc6slx45-3csg324.
- Tools: Version 14.2 of Xilinx ISE

As I'm really new to FPGAs, I was wondering if there's someone there who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Some more details would be useful: What FPGA?  What version of Xilinx tools?  How did you create the code that instantiates the DCM_BASE?

Comment: Using Xilinx xc6slx45 - 3csg324. Version 14.2 of Xilinx tools. I didn't create any code to instantiate the DCM_BASE. Thanks for your reply...

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a file in your design, DCM_BASE is just a wrapper for DCM_ADV, you can find it on internet if you search for it. It is not device dependent, it is just a simple VHDL file generated by the Xilinx CoreGen. There is a nice User Guide from Xilinx that describes how to use this CoreGen, just in case you are interested in learning about it.
[Xilinx user Guide to know more about clock generator and how to use it.](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug190.pdf)

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your helpful reply. I'm trying to get this bitcoin miner to work: https://github.com/progranism/Open-Source-FPGA-Bitcoin-Miner/tree/master/projects/VHDL_Xilinx_Port What file is missing do you think?

Comment: Because I'm using a Spartan, I changed DCM_BASE to DCM_SP (and removed a couple of non-applicable signals) and it worked!

Comment: Now my design won't fit on the device ;( Shucks...

Comment: You can change the parameters of your design to fit the smaller FPGA, read the documentation, you will find it there.

Answer (score 0):

Your device is a Spartan-6.
In this family, the DCM primitive is `DCM_SP` or `DCM_CLKGEN` http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug382.pdf.

I have used:

```
  Library UNISIM;
    use UNISIM.vcomponents.all;

   I_DCM: dcm_clkgen
       generic map (
           clkfx_multiply    => 3,
           clkfx_divide      => 8,
           clkin_period      => 10.0
       )
       port map (
           rst       => '0',
           freezedcm => '0',
           clkin     => clock,
           clkfx     => clockDiv
       );
```

which worked for me.